Debugging Nextjs Server Side with Webstorm 2024 and Typescript
Has anyone successfully been able to debug Next.js Typescript in Webstorm?

this is my dev script in package.json: "dev": "turbo run --env-mode=loose --filter=./apps/* --filter=. dev watch:packages",
this runs 4 different Next.js apps.
the issue I am having is, if i run a npm script run/debug it runs okay, but if I have any breakpoint inside a separate code that is inside packages such as these:
"dependencies": {
    "@ourPackages/admin-utils": "workspace:*",
    "@ourPackages/auth": "workspace:*",
    "@ourPackages/billing": "workspace:*",
    "@ourPackages/cms": "workspace:*",
    "@ourPackages/config": "workspace:*",
    "@ourPackages/coupon": "workspace:*",
    }

My breakpoints inside these packages are being skipped. I am suspecting its related to how the import and typescript compiling works.

Did you have any luck? I am encountering the same issue.
